# Provisioning error

Tags: php, vagrant, composer-php, puphpet

Since yesterday I have an odd error during provisioning my VM.

```
Error: curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php returned 255 instead of one of [0]
```

It's odd because this command works fine on the machine. It seems that only response code is not valid.

Comment: [A lot of people](https://github.com/puphpet/puphpet/issues/1374) is facing the same problem, including me

Comment: OK. It seems to be global problem. Thanks. https://github.com/puphpet/puphpet/issues/2098

Answer (score 3):

There seems to have been some change made to Composer's servers. I'm not sure of what, but curl was no longer succeeding for installation process.

This issue has been resolved in this commit, though: https://github.com/puphpet/puppet-puphpet/commit/659fc6d6548dd8158fdac7bb834111c769854a98

Either apply the patch manually or regenerate your archive from the puphpet gui and you'll be set.